# Powershell Invoke-RestMethod with body begins from array

Tags: powershell, rest, invoke-webrequest, invoke-restmethod

I have a web server  that responds to a request  https://localhost/GetUpdateInfo with a body  [{"ipAddress": "10.200.2.55"}]
In postman its Work but in powershell i can`t do this because body begins from array.

When i do exmple code:

```
$Url = "https://localhost/GetUpdateInfo"
$Body = @(@{
    ipAddress = "10.200.2.55"
    })
      $jsonBody = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $Body
Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Post' -Uri $url  -Body $jsonBody
```

i hve error: Invoke-RestMethod : Block length does not match with its complement.

Answer (score 1):

The content type of all POST requests is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` unless specified.

Add `-ContentType application/json` to your last line call so your json is sent correctly.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Post' -Uri $url  -Body $jsonBody -ContentType 'application/json'
```

Comment: Noting changed: Invoke-RestMethod : Block length does not match with its complement. \n How can i send request  with a RAW body?

Comment: @Pomidor_83 What is a "raw body" ? If you mean that you don't want to include the contenttype, set it to an empty string (eg: `-ContentType ''`. It won't be there at all. If you set it to `$null`  or don't put any, www-form-urlencoded will be used.